# Is there a portable alternative to LTspice?

Tags: spice, ltspice

I am constantly on the move and come across many computers to which I have access and which have some version of Windows installed. I was wondering if there's a portable alternative to LTspice (or if there's a way (a wrapper or something equivalent) by which I can install it on my USB stick and use it anywhere)?

A quick Google search revealed no obvious alternative. There are a few online spice simulators  like [circuitlab.com](http://circuitlab.com), [partsim.com](http://partsim.com) and [ngspice.com](http://ngspice.com). But none are too keen to explain their limitations for free use. For instance, I tried reading the terms of service for partsim.com, but that too wasn't very enlightening. I wanted some advice before signing up.

Comment: LTSpice is essentially portable already - it doesn't need any registry entries or admin privileges to work. Just copy the folder over to your flash drive and away you go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LTSpice is essentially portable already - it doesn't need any registry entries or admin privileges to work. Just copy the folder over to your flash drive and away you go.

Comment: I've used LTSpice like this for years ... except now my PC  has been locked down so that Any unknown exe requires admin. This is a very recent issue for me but all the previous PC's this worked on... I get round this by asking IT to install it. This does require a Boss and IT to agree. In most cases a free repected engineering tool shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It seems to store preferences to a Windows directory.. is there a way to change that?

Answer (score 1):

Considered an Smartphone app? Not as functional as LTSpice but works for simple things:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.everycircuit

It is also available as an online application for Google Chrome:

http://everycircuit.com/app

Answer (score 0):

You could make a bootable USB stick with Linux on it and run LTSpice from Wine.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1824277

Or make a virtual machine and bring the "virtual file" with you. VirtualBox for instance. But then you have to install the VirtualBox application on every computer, and I guess that is as bad (or worse) as installing LTSpice on them.

Comment: VirtualBox will not run well without admin privileges (needs a kernel driver for hardware accelerated virtualization). LTSpice is already portable, it can be copied to a folder and run directly.

Comment: True about VB. Sorry about the n00b question, but if LTSpice is portable, why not post is as an answer?

Comment: I guess that's a good point. Done.